# GRUB: how to change default disk for future OS updates?

Tags: grub2

I'm running Debian testing on a computer with 2 disks:

/dev/sda:

- /dev/sda1 - data disk

/dev/sdb:

- /dev/sdb1 - Linux Mint (no longer used)
- /dev/sdb2 - /home
- /dev/sdb3 - Debian testing (current OS)

Yesterday I updated Debain testing, including a new kernel. GRUB was also updated, but the GRUB menu didn't change. After doing a `grub-install /dev/sdb` manually I discovered my updated kernel and was able to boot it.

I suspect that Debian testing updates GRUB on /dev/sda, which is ignored when I boot. How can I configure GRUB such that it will write a new bootloader config to /dev/sdb?

I'm using GRUB 2.02.

Cheers,

Enno